# Open modal box isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This code open a modal box. But my problem is when I tried to open it with a different id for my edit purposes the modal box isn't working. I want to add this code `<input type="button" value="Edit Item" id="edit">`open a modal box using another id. But why isn't working?

```
<input type="button" value="Add New Item" id="add_new">

<div class="entry-form">
<form name="userinfo" id="userinfo">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" align="right"><a href="#" id="close">Close</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Item</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="items" id="items" value="" class="inputs" autocomplete="off"></td>
    </tr>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#add_new").click(function(){
        $(".entry-form").fadeIn("fast");    
    });

    $("#close").click(function(){
        $(".entry-form").fadeOut("fast");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Invalid markup, neither the form, the table or the wrapping div are closed.

Comment: @adeneo why it closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `#edit` to the click event handler as well, as you can see in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Fhz8/1/).

```
 <input type="button" value="Add New Item" id="add_new">
 <input type="button" value="Edit Item" id="edit">

 <div class="entry-form">
 <form name="userinfo" id="userinfo">
     <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="right"><a href="#" id="close">Close</a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>Item</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="items" id="items" value="" class="inputs" autocomplete="off"></td>
     </tr>
 <div>
```

And your Javascript:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

       $("#add_new, #edit").click(function(){
           $(".entry-form").fadeIn("fast");
       });

       $("#close").click(function(){
           $(".entry-form").fadeOut("fast");
       });
   });
```

Comment: Thanks :) I have another question regarding with this. I'll post another question can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

First, your HTML is broken as you haven't added closing tags for any of the following:
first div, form, table, second div.

Second, your script should have a `type="text/javascript"` attribute.

Comment: type in script is not necesary in this case

Comment: I saw some non-modern HTML re the table structure the OP gave, so this is not an HTML5 snippet. Per W3C specs, I believe type="text/javascript" is required for pre HTML5 versions.